# How to add an index of a data frame between existing indexes in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

[image]

It has a data frame in the form shown above.

Convert this data frame to pivot_table

[image]

However, the data frame that I want is range(0,10) for grid_x and range(0,20) for grid_y,

and I want to be filled with zeros if there is no.

example

| grid_x \grid_y | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | 19 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ... | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ... | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ... | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ... | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ... | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ... | 0 |
| 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ... | 0 |
| 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ... | 0 |
| 8 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | ... | 0 |
| 9 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | ... | 0 |

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['grid_x'], df['grid_y']).reindex(np.arange(10)).reindex(np.arange(20), axis=1)`

Comment: @QuangHoang thank. but crosstab is same result.
What I want is that even if there is no value in the dataframe, I want the number of indexes and columns that I specified (example, grid_x=10 and grid_y=20) to be created.

Comment: See editted comment with `reindex`, pass `fill_value=0` to each of the reindex.